# Xcode Analyzer vs OCLint in 2016

Tags: ios, xcode, static-analysis, xcode-bots, oclint

Is there any reason to use OCLint over Xcode's Analyze tool on Xcode 7?

All the posts and information that I can find online date from 2013 or older, but I know Xcode improved quite a bit with it's tools since then, like we didn't have code coverage before Xcode 7 (just to name an example).

I've been asked to perform continuous static code analysis on my project and I have setup Xcode Server with a bot to do continuos integration with the Analyzer on. But now I wonder if I should also do a post build script to run OCLint as well (or maybe instead?)

Comment: Xcode's(clang) analyzer and OCLint differ in number of checkers they implement. You can compare them by yourself and find out that OCLint adds a handful of really useful ones. Therewith OCLint allows you to run clang analyzer checkers at the same time as OCLint's own (option -enable-clang-static-analyzer). Also consider reading this post https://codeascraft.com/2014/01/15/static-analysis-with-oclint/